# for Loop in Java - exponents

Tags: java, for-loop, exponentiation

Basically, there is a group of 20 sheep. After the group has grown to a population of 80 sheep, the group does not need to be supervised anymore. The number of sheep, N, each year, t, is found with :

N = 220/(1 + 10(0.83)^t)

This program tries to find out how many years the sheep have to be supervised and writes out  the value of N for t starting at zero and going up to 25.

This is my code so far...it doesn't seem to work and I know there is something to do with the part about multiplying with the power. I'm trying to use a variable "power" that is multiplied by 0.83 in each iteration of the loop. Any help is appreciated,  thank you.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("A breeding group of 20 bighorn sheep is released in a protected area in Colorado.");
    System.out.println("After the group has reached a size of 80 sheep, the group does not need to be supervised anymore.");
    System.out.println("This program calculates how many years the sheep have to be supervised.");
    int number = 20;
    int power = 1;
    for(int years = 0; number < 80; power*= 0.83) {
        number = 220 / (1 + 10 * power);           
        System.out.println("After " + years + " years, the number of sheep is: " + number);
        years++;
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: You are doing all your calculation with integers when you should be using `double`. The first time you execute `power *= 0.83` the value of `power` is zero.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: I would use [Math.pow(double, double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your data types on number and power from int to double. I tried it and it runs correctly. You also might want to modify your for loop to run while years < 25 rather than number < 80. And make number a local variable inside the loop for cleanliness.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("A breeding group of 20 bighorn sheep is released in a protected area in Colorado.");
    System.out.println("After the group has reached a size of 80 sheep, the group does not need to be supervised anymore.");
    System.out.println("This program calculates how many years the sheep have to be supervised.");
    double power = 1;
    boolean foundFirstOverEighty = false;
    for (int years = 0; years < 25; years++) {
        double number = 220 / (1 + 10 * power);
        System.out.println("After " + years + " years, the number of sheep is: " + number);

        if (!foundFirstOverEighty && number >= 80) {
            System.out.println("First time number of sheep exceeded eighty. " + years + " years. number of sheep is: " + number);
            foundFirstOverEighty = true;
        }

        power *= 0.83;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot but I'm wondering how do I extract the exact year when the sheep first came over 80?

Comment: :) added the first over 80 check